# Editing a set (for example tags) in event sourcing

Tags: data-structures, tags, set, event-sourcing

Say we have a simple "concept" Car with those properties (using pseudocode, this question is language agnostic):

```
Car
{
    string Brand;
    string[] Tags;
}
```

Note that I have not said this is a class of code, nor this is a database object or anything... this is just a "concept" in our domain.

For this example we'll assume tags are free text, not selected from a closed-collection of tags like it happens in stack-overflow where the tags "refer" to the "real tag entity". In this example they are just strings over there.

Let's assume we are using a CQRS + Event Sourcing for this application so we will be able to track when the car was created, who edited it, etc.

Our first application requirements require us to "create cars" but not edit them. Naturally the creation event could easily be seen as:

```
CarCreated( string Brand, string[] Tags );
```

One month after, they request us to edit cars. They want to edit the brand and the tags.

Of course, the car edition of the brand or the tags is independent, and we could have 2 approaches here:

```
Approach 1) There are 2 events, one for each thing:
CarBrandEdited( [pass here the brand info] )
CarTagsEdited( [pass here the tags info] )
```

or

```
Approach 2) There is a single atomic edition event
    that may touch one or the other or both:
CarEdited( [pass here the edition definition] )
```

Define one or the other approach I feel it's rather "domain-based"... You cannot change a date by changing its "day" and then its "month" as in between there is a micro-second gap where the date is incorrect.

Either it is "4th-jul" or "18th-aug" but never "18th-jul" as it would happen if we first update the day and later the month. This means "making those 2 changes atomic".

My question specifically arises around the TAGS thing...

If I have this set of tags for an object:

```
green kitcheeeen tall wood
```

and I give a form to a user and the user inputs:

```
green kitchen metal soft
```

How would I have to proceed?

- Option a)

  - Tags edited, new tags = "green kitchen metal"
- Option b)

  - Tag kitcheeeen removed
  - Tag tall removed
  - Tag wood removed
  - Tag kitchen added
  - Tag metal added
  - Tag soft added
- Option c) (probably not doing a form, but giving the user crosses to remove and pencils to edit text)

  - Tag kitcheeeen changed for kitchen
  - Tag tall removed
  - Tag wood changed for metal
  - Tag soft added

I don't enter in the issue if those changes should be "atomic" all in one event or "spread" into seaparate events... What I'm interested in is:

For me option C is the one more purist and the one that conveys more "meaning" to the event... but that is an overkill in programming the user interface to allow the user distinguish if

1. a text-change is an edition (like wood for metal, as it seems a material change, probably the user would edit the tag in a box) or
2. a text-change is just a removal and a separate addition (like dropping tall and adding soft, probably the user would press a `x` on the tall and clicking `+` would have a blank textbox to enter a new tag.

Reinforce by the idea that tags are "meaning semantics", Option C seems "the one". But it's overkill in the front makes me thing if I'm missing a good-albeit-simpler solution.

How should the `CarEdited` event be defined?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it depends on the question: "does tracking this brings business value?"

If you see business value in knowing if the user edited a tag directly or by deleting/rewriting it, if you believe you will need to know this in the future, then option C is the way to go.

But in most cases it's perfectly fine to just store the event `CarEdited { newBrand, newTags }`.

---

*Side notes:*

I never used that but I read that it's useful to have reversible events, maybe you want to store the event `CarEdited { oldBrand, newBrand, oldTags, newTags }`.

Also, one great thing about Event Sourcing is that it emancipates you from CRUD language and replace it by business language. I guess your user didn't *create* the car, they just registered it in your system, maybe you want to call the first event `CarRegistered` instead of `CarCreated`.

Hope this helps!